# How to solve the PDE $2u_x − u_y = 10u + 5e^{ x−3y} , u(x, 0) = x^2 e^{4x} − e^x$ .

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I can't figure out what method to use for this question. I tried the coordinate method to find the equation, but that didn't work. Then I tried the Lagrange's auxiliary equations method, but that didn't work either. I'm just trying to find the appropriate method to solve the above PDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it using the same method used to solve linear inhomogeneous ODEs: write the solution as $u=v+w$, where $v$ is the general solution to the homogeneous PDE,
$$
2v_x-v_y=10v, \tag{1}
$$
and $w$ is a particular solution to the inhomogeneous PDE,
$$
2w_x-w_y=10w+5e^{x-3y}. \tag{2}
$$
By inspection, it's easy to guess that Eq. $(2)$ has a particular solution of the form $w(x,y)=Ae^{x-3y}$ (I leave it to you to determine $A$). It's also simple to find the general solution to Eq. $(1)$ by solving the Lagrange-Charpit equations,
$$
\frac{dx}{2}=\frac{dy}{-1}=\frac{dv}{10v}. \tag{3}
$$
It's so simple, in fact, that I'll just write the result: $v(x,y)=e^{5x}f(x+2y)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary differentiable function. Therefore, the general solution to the original PDE is
$$
u(x,y)=v(x,y)+w(x,y)=e^{5x}f(x+2y)+Ae^{x-3y}. \tag{4}
$$
Finally, use the boundary condition $u(x,0)=x^2e^{4x}-e^x$ to determine $f$.

Comment: thanks! For eq 2, how did you guess the particular solution is of that form? We just started learning pdes, so I'm not quite sure.

Comment: The exponential function has this property: $\frac{d}{dz}e^{cz}=ce^{cz}$.

Comment: oh yes I do know that, but I'm confused as to how you solved the entire equation. Like there were more parts to it, how did you differentiate $e^{x-3y}$ only?

Comment: Are you familiar with linear ODEs? With the method of undetermined coefficients?

Comment: yes I am. I just tried it on equation 2 and got A=-1, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.